# cv_bridge.core.CvBridgeError: [8UC1] is not a color format. but [bgr8] is

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I have a bag file recorded with the IR sensor of a realsense SR300 camera.
I am trying to convert it in a video with bag2video.py file, but it turns out this result:

```
cv_bridge.core.CvBridgeError: [8UC1] is not a color format. but [bgr8] is. The conversion does not make sense
```

I've found the problem and I've understood it, but actually I don't know how to solve it!!
Please can you help me??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310961/cv_bridge.core.cvbridgeerror:-%5B8uc1%5D-is-not-a-color-format.-but-%5Bbgr8%5D-is./) by [alessiadele](https://answers.ros.org/users/38779/alessiadele/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-18**:
Are you trying to encode a color video format? I suspect you'll need to specify the video as greyscale to get this to work.

**Comment by [alessiadele](https://answers.ros.org/users/38779/alessiadele/) on 2018-12-18**:
I used all the three different parameters for "--encode" (rgb8, bgr8, mono8), but the program always gives me the same error.
I don't know how to specify the video as greyscale!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just had a quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/OSUrobotics/bag2video/blob/master/bag2video.py) for this and it seems the encoding option is not implemented. It's actually hard coded to use `bgr8` and ignores whatever you specify as the encoding!

Since It's a python file you could dig in and change the hard coded encoding format yourself or get it to use the encoding value correctly.

Hope this helps.

Update:

You'll need to change line 53 which is currently:

```
img = np.asarray(bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, 'bgr8'))
```

so that the encoding you want to use is in the inverted commas instead such as

```
img = np.asarray(bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, 'mono8'))
```

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alessiadele](https://answers.ros.org/users/38779/alessiadele/) on 2018-12-18**:
Yes, unfortunately I am not a programmer, so I don't know how to change the code, or wich line I should add in the python file!

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-18**:
I've added some instructions for you.

**Comment by [alessiadele](https://answers.ros.org/users/38779/alessiadele/) on 2018-12-18**:
Thank you very much!
I've followed your instructions, but now the error is:

cv_bridge.core.CvBridgeError: [8UC1] is not a color format. but [mono8] is.

I am trying to read and understand something more about 8UC1, ROS images and OpenCV images, but it's a little bit complicated, you're right!

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-18**:
according to the documentation for `imgmsg_to_cv2` you can give it an encoding of `passthrough` and it will not try and change it. This might be worth a go.

**Comment by [alessiadele](https://answers.ros.org/users/38779/alessiadele/) on 2018-12-18**:
Thank you Pete!!
I've solved (in part) the problem modifying the line that you said to me in this way:

```
img = np.asarray(bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, '8UC1'))
```

Now the program does convert the bag file in a video, but it doesn't save any file, it just shows me it!
Thank you very much!! :D

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-18**:
Great. Can you accept my answer by clicking the tick next to it. This way other users can see that a solution was found.